# Pandas interpolating date across columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, interpolation

I have the following pd dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([pd.datetime(2016,1,1), pd.datetime(2016,2,1)], columns = ['d1'])
df['d2'] = [pd.datetime(2016,1,5), pd.datetime(2016,2,10)]
df['d3'] = [pd.datetime(2016,1,10), pd.datetime(2016,2,20)]
df['v1'], df['v2'], df['v3'] = [1,10], [5, 100], [5, 100]
df['x1'] = [pd.datetime(2016,1,2), pd.datetime(2016,2,13)]


          d1         d2         d3  v1   v2   v3         x1
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-05 2016-01-10   1    5    5 2016-01-02
1 2016-02-01 2016-02-10 2016-02-20  10  100  100 2016-02-13
```

I would like to calculate column x2 by interpolating

```
x: x1
independent = [d1, d2, d3]
dependent = [v1, v2, v3]
```

In the example above, x2 should be 2 for row 0, 100 for row 1.

I can think of using df.iterrows(), slice [d1-d3] and [v1-v3], then use np.interp, but even that gets a little complex since I have to convert dates into float. (np.interp takes lists of floats only).

There should be a cleaner, vectorized approach within Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Pandas can interpolate using specific columns as IVs and DVs.  However, you can get what you want if you think of the timestamps as a single Series.

With a little shuffling, we can reformat the dataframe for [`interpolate(method='time')`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html#pandas.Series.interpolate), and then put it back into its original format. Starting with your sample data frame, add on an empty `x2`:

```
import numpy as np
df['x2'] = np.nan 

df
          d1         d2         d3  v1   v2   v3         x1  x2
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-05 2016-01-10   1    5    5 2016-01-02 NaN
1 2016-02-01 2016-02-10 2016-02-20  10  100  100 2016-02-13 NaN
```

Now swing from wide to long, and condense into just two columns, `d` and `v` (`x` gets honorary membership in the `d` and `v` clubs for now).  Save the actual column names as indices:

```
pairs = [('d1','v1'), ('d2','v2'), ('d3','v3'), ('x1','x2')]
df2 = pd.concat(
    (df[[d, v]].rename(index=lambda i: d,
                       columns=lambda x: 'd' if (x[0]=='d') | (x=='x1') else 'v') for d, v in pairs))

df2

            d      v
d1 2016-01-01    1.0
d1 2016-02-01   10.0
d2 2016-01-05    5.0
d2 2016-02-10  100.0
d3 2016-01-10    5.0
d3 2016-02-20  100.0
x1 2016-01-02    NaN
x1 2016-02-13    NaN
```

We want to `interpolate` based on time, so we'll move timestamps into the index, sort by date, and then perform the interpolation:

```
df3 = (df2.reset_index()
          .set_index(pd.to_datetime(df2.d))
          .drop('d', 1)
          .sort_index()
          .interpolate(method="time")
          .sort_values('index')
      )

df3
           index      v
d                      
2016-01-01    d1    1.0
2016-02-01    d1   10.0
2016-01-05    d2    5.0
2016-02-10    d2  100.0
2016-01-10    d3    5.0
2016-02-20    d3  100.0
2016-01-02    x1    2.0
2016-02-13    x1  100.0
```

The interpolation is correct, per OP expected output.  Now we just need to get the data frame back into its original shape.  We do this by setting the indices back to `0`/`1`, based on odd/even row numbers, and then using `pivot()`:

```
df4 = df3.reset_index().rename(index=lambda x: int(x%2)).pivot(columns='index')
df4.columns = df4.columns.droplevel(0)
iv, dv = zip(*pairs)
df4.columns = iv + dv

df4
          d1         d2         d3         x1    v1     v2     v3     x2
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-05 2016-01-10 2016-01-02   1.0    5.0    5.0    2.0
1 2016-02-01 2016-02-10 2016-02-20 2016-02-13  10.0  100.0  100.0  100.0
```

There may be a stealthier way to reshape things in the middle, but the key intuition here is that Pandas will interpolate missing values using time as a reference, if given the proper format.

**UPDATE** (per comments)
If interpolation must occur per-row, we can use a similar method as above, with `apply()`:

```
def custom_interp(row, pairs):
    data = pd.concat(
        (pd.DataFrame(row[[d, v]]).rename(index=lambda x: 'd' if (x[0] == 'd') | (x == 'x1') else 'v',
                                          columns=lambda x: d) for d, v in pairs), 
        axis=1).T.reset_index()
    data = (data.set_index(pd.to_datetime(data.d))
                .drop('d', 1)
                .sort_index()
           )
    data.v = data.v.astype(float)
    data = data.interpolate(method='time').reset_index()
    data.index = np.repeat(row.name, len(data.index))
    data = data.pivot(columns='index')
    data.columns = data.columns.droplevel(0)
    return data.values[0]

df.apply(custom_interp, args=(pairs,), axis=1)

          d1         d2         d3         v1    v2     v3     x1     x2
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-05 2016-01-10 2016-01-02   1.0    5.0    5.0    2.0
1 2016-02-01 2016-02-10 2016-02-20 2016-02-13  10.0  100.0  100.0  100.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Like the idea, but interpolation needs to be done row-wise. Your example df2 combines d's and v's from all rows.

Comment: In the example data you provided, the dates in each row formed periods that didn't overlap across rows. Are there some cases in your data where this kind of overlap will occur?

Comment: Yes, sorry my example was poor. There are overlaps. Better example is to replace all 'Feb' to 'Jan' in row 1.

Comment: I think the same approach should be possible, if we interpolate after grouping all the dates in a row. I'll have a look tomorrow and see what I can come up with.